# MongoDB/Mongoose query to filter all the value in an array based on their presence in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array lets say [1,2,3] and a collection called 'Numbers' and it has a field called 'value'. I need to retain all the values in the array which are present against the 'value' field in any document in the collection.

Example,

```
Test array - [1,2,3]
Numbers collection - [{value: 1}, {value: 3}]
Result should be - [1,3]
```

Result is that way because '2' was not present against 'value' field in any documents within 'Numbers' collection.

How do i do this?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you done already?

Comment: I have not written the code for this logic as i dont know how to do it!! Thats why i have given what my test array is and sample collection is and what my output should be!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below `distinct` query with projection and query filter.

```
db.Numbers.distinct( "value", { "value": { $in: [1,2,3] } } )
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works cool. If incase the 'value' is an ObjectID in a separate collection and if i need to do the same logic , how would i do that?